# How to determine direction in self-referential one-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up a self-referential one-to-many relationship in a Flask application using SQLAlchemy.

```
from app import db
[...]
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    children = db.relationship("Task", backref='parent',
                               remote_side=[id])
```

I am attempting to implement something like the example from [this page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html) on Adjacency List Relationships on the SQLAlchemy tutorial. Each task node may have many children and only one parent.

The relationship is working right now but the wrong way around from what I had intended ie. a task with parent_id of 1, will list the task with id = 1 as its child. Equally, Task.parent returns a list.

Alembic, the migration tool, encoded the above as the following:

```
    op.add_column('tasks', sa.Column('parent_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'tasks', 'tasks', ['parent_id'], ['id'])
```

My assumption is that I have provided the wrong syntax for the remote_side declaration which is absent from the above. Unfortunately, self-referential relationships throw me every time and I cannot get my head around how this is to work. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the modules you're using, so I won't put a full answer together. I think you might be better off giving each Task its own parent, so switch `children` to `parent`. Basically, when you create a new Task, you're not saying "and here are the n children," you're saying "and Task's parent is x". Then, you can find all the Tasks with `parent.id = 1`. It might actually be working as expected if you switch your mentality of the words "parent" and "children" right now. `Task.parent` returns a list, aka a list of children, right?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I did wonder if it might be a question of switching my mentality. In the end, though, the answer below nails it in terms of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you have linked, declaring your relationships may either be done by:

```
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    parent = db.relationship("Task", backref='children',
                               remote_side=[id])
```

or

```
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    children = db.relationship("Task", backref=backref('parent',
                               remote_side=[id]))
```

Note that in the second case, the remote_side parameter is provided to the backref function, not to the relationship. The code you show is an hybrid of the two (you declare the children relation, but the remote_side declaration is outside the backref call).

This is because `remote_side=['id']` declares the field that is the key that is being referenced by the foreign_key, and thus must be added to the relationship that points to the '1' side of the relation (the parent).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Yes, I mangled it a little from the documentation. This is one of those things I approach in the assumption I can't understand it; it turns into a self-fulfiling prophecy. Your explanation of remote_side is just what I needed. The SQLAlchemy tutorial is very good but there are a handful of things I can't grasp from it.